# Track total visit time

Tags: php, ajax

I found on Stackoverflow
a Ajax script to track the total `visit time from a visitor`.
But it register only my `own visit-time`...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var start = null;
    $(window).load(function(event) {
      start = event.timeStamp;
    });
    $(window).unload(function(event) {
      var time = event.timeStamp - start;
      $.post('visit-timer/ajax-backend.php', {time: time});
    })
  });
</script>

<?php 
  $time = intval($_POST['time']);
  if (!file_exists('data1.php')) {
    file_put_contents('data1.php', $time . "---$ip---\r\n");
  } else {
    file_put_contents('data1.php', $time . "---$ip---\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
  }
?>
```

Comment: How do you mean it logs only your own visit.

Comment: Means you are the only visitor for the code. Have you deployed this code anywhere?

Comment: Thamilan I deployed the code on my index page for testing if it is working... Like I say it register only my own visit, but I had other visitors on the index page...   I hope someone have a solution for me ???